# Who else is feeling hot (besides/ beside) me?

Tags: prepositions

What should be used in this sentence:

> Who else is feeling hot (*besides/ beside*) me?

Answer (score -1):

'Besides' would be correct because of number agreement. Who else refers to multiple people (because it is never said when you are just talking to someone else.) in a group, and besides is also plural.